# How to configure pfSense to allow/deny web sites on a per client (or ip range) basis

Tags: networking, access-control-list, pfsense

I would like to know how to implement a more granular filtering in pfSense.

Scenario:

- pfSense with 2 WAN and 1 LAN
- 160 clients with DHCP

I would like to know how to allow websites on a per client basis.

Example:

- group A allow websites X and deny websites Y
- group B allow websites X and allow websites Y
- group C allow websites X and allow websites Y and allow websites Z

How is a configuration like this done?

Thanks for the help

Ern

Comment: @mzhaase Very helpful edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **Squid**. Perhaps as a transparent proxy? Up to you...

Install the `squid` package on your pfSense firewall from **System->Package Manager**.

Go to **Services->Squid Proxy Server->General** and at the bottom click **Show Advanced Options**

Here you can add custom ACLs in the boxes. See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl for details on that. You can get the fine control that you need, it's just a matter of reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

pfBlockerNG can do this.

Also, the new tag feature in Unbound can do this, with no additional components needed. More details at Unbound's [home](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/blog/2016/12/22/client-based-filtering-in-unbound/).

It's only supported in Unbound 1.5.10 onwards, so you may need to update your pfSense.

The config is a bit long winded, even convoluted, sophistication comes with [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophistication_(complexity_theory)). Perhaps a pfSense GUI for it might appear for it in the future. It is a new feature.

pfSense web admin gui > Services > DNS Resolver > Custom Options

```
# give pfSense a server: tag so it puts directives in correct place
server:                                      

# define a new tag
define-tag: "websiteX"
define-tag: "websiteY"
define-tag: "websiteZ"

# create access control entry
access-control: 10.1.1.0/24 allow  # group A
access-control: 10.1.2.0/24 allow  # group B
access-control: 10.1.3.0/24 allow  # group C

# tag the access
# allocate ip ranges to the tag
access-control-tag: 10.1.1.0/24 "websiteX"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.2.0/24 "websiteX"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.3.0/24 "websiteX"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.1.0/24 "websiteY"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.2.0/24 "websiteY"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.3.0/24 "websiteY"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.1.0/24 "websiteZ"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.2.0/24 "websiteZ"     
access-control-tag: 10.1.3.0/24 "websiteZ"     

# create the local-zone, and allow normal service 
#  which allows non-blocked users access
#  and allow all types like A and AAAA and CNAME    
local-zone: www.websitex.com typetransparent  
local-zone: www.websitey.com typetransparent  
local-zone: www.websitez.com typetransparent  

# tag the domain
local-zone-tag: www.websitex.com websiteX       
local-zone-tag: www.websitey.com websiteY
local-zone-tag: www.websitez.com websiteZ       

# ensure local data served first
access-control-tag-action: 10.1.1.0/24 "websiteY" redirect  
access-control-tag-action: 10.1.2.0/24 "websiteZ" redirect  

# Send users to your polite internal block page
access-control-tag-data: 10.1.1.0/24 "websiteY" "A 10.1.1.1"
access-control-tag-data: 10.1.2.0/24 "websiteZ" "A 10.1.1.1"
```